# Package Feature Selection for text classification in R

Tags: r, text-mining, text-classification, feature-selection

I would like to do feature selection for binary text classification in R before training the model.
Is there any package (similar to TextFeatureSelection in python) that can be applied?
Or does anybody have an example of how to apply something like Proportional Difference or Information Gain in R for Text?

Thank you very much!

Comment: [Supervised Machine Learning for Text Analysis in R](https://smltar.com/preface.html) is good on feature selection for text.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an approach based on AUC. If you have a large number of variables (i. e. mat_Features) that you can use to predict a "zero / one variable" (i. e. zero_One_Var), you can calculate the AUC for every variables in the matrix mat_Features. You could, for example, keep all the variables that have an AUC > 0.65. Here is an example :

```
library(pROC)

x <- mat_Features
y <- zero_One_Var

nb_Col <- ncol(x)
vec_AUC <- rep(NA, nb_Col)

for(i in 1 : nb_Col)
{
  print(i)
  vec_AUC[i] <- roc(y, x[, i])$auc
}
```